# Using dart:io WebSocket with wss:// protocol (SSL)

Tags: ssl, websocket, dart

I tried to use the [WebSocket class](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/WebSocket.html) in the `dart:io` package to connect to an SSL WebSocket service. This doesn't seem to work. Isn't the `wss://` protocol supported at the moment or am I missing something. Here is the code used:

```dart
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://...');

ws.onopen = () {
    print('open');
};

ws.onmessage = (e) {
    print(e.data);
};
```

I also tried the alternative API:

```dart
var client = new HttpClient(),
    conn = new WebSocketClientConnection(client.getUrl(new Uri.fromString('https://...')));

    conn.onMessage = (msg) {
        print(msg);
    };

    conn.onOpen = () {
        print('open');
    };
```

This doesn't seem to work either, I get errors like:

> 1006 HttpParserException: Connection closed before full response
>   header was received 1006 HttpParserException: Invalid request method

I am using the latest SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are the latest version of Dart. I would recommend updating if you are not.

Some of the methods you are calling - `conn.onMessage()`, `conn.onOpen()` return `Stream` objects and you need to use a `.listen()` to access ('listen to') the stream.  Here is the syntax:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var wss = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');
  wss.onOpen.listen((item) {
    wss.send("hello world");
  });

  wss.onMessage.listen((message) {
    print(message.data);
  });
}
```

etc.

Can you try that?  For more details, read about [Stream](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Stream.html) and [Websocket](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/WebSocket.html) in the api docs.

Comment: I want to use websocket on the server side (i.e. DartVM). Anyway the second alternative actually works in the latest SDK.

Comment: Great. Things have changed quite a bit with the M3 changes. Your `onOpen` and `onMessage` should also work in the way I have demonstrated above.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the second alternative works in the latest SDK. The problem was that I was connecting to a Socket.io service and I wasn't performing the HTTP handshake.